# Blocks are coming in other theme also magento2

Tags: blocks

I created a theme named (Inf) with some blocks. In this theme the blocks are coming fine.I'll attach a screenshot below. then,
I created one more theme named (Soll) with no blocks.Next, I want to switch the theme from Inf to Soll and did it perfectly from backend.
Now, the blocks are not coming fine in Soll theme. Ofcorse I dont want them in second theme . Can anybody plz help to remove those Blocks ??
 [image: Inf theme with blocks]
[image: Soll theme with blocks(i didn't add them.)]

Comment: You are saying Blocks are not coming. Also you don't want the blocks then what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Yes. In one theme i want blocks and in another theme i dont want the blocks. What is the solution ???

Comment: Can you check xmls? You will find the block names cms_index_index.xml if its a homepage. Or if they are using simple content from cms page then you cannot change it  on that way.